How to load a non-padding tile to share memory with cublasdx::copy
I am trying the library cublasdx (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublasdx/index.html) to do a batch of non-uniform gemm. cublasdx provides an efficient way (cublasdx::copy) to load tile to share memory. But it only works for some pre-compiled tile size, like GEMM(32,32,32). Here is my question, is it possible to use cublasdx::copy<GEMM(32,32,32)> to load a non-padding tile (like (10,32,16) ) to share memory?
Thanks!
